# concatenate string from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, string, esri, arcgis-js-api

I would like to pull the longitudes and latitudes from an ESRI geometry and concatenate them in to a long string (to be used in an API call).

I am struggling with how to accomplish this

The ESRI documentation for geometry ([geometry specs](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/geometry.html)) shows the structure of the object but my API call needs the latitude/longitudes in the following format:

```
long1,lat1,long2,lat2,long3,lat3 ...  long1, lat1
```

All I have to do is process the long/lats a little bit.  Making a very simple example from the ESRI documentation

```
        MyTest = {
                    "rings": [
                        [
                            [-97.06138, 32.837],
                            [-97.06133, 32.836],
                            [-97.06124, 32.834],
                            [-97.06127, 32.832],
                            [-97.06138, 32.837]
                        ]
                    ],
                    "spatialReference": {
                        "wkid": 4326
                    }
                };

        alert(JSON.stringify(MyTest.rings[0]));
```

Will give me the rings (the Longitudes/Latitudes) (notice the first long/lat is repeated as the last long/lat)

I cannot seem to figure out how to strip off the [ and ] to create a string with just the longitudes and latitudes.  For instance:

```
myTest2 = MyTest.rings[0];  // get the longitudes and latitudes
myTest3 = JSON.stringify(myTest2);
myTest4 = myTest3.replace("[","");

alert(JSON.stringify(myTest2));

alert(JSON.stringify(myTest4));
```

The replace will strip off one of the brackets but I cannot get it to do a global replace like this post [stack javascript replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript) because my programming environment is all within ColdFusion and I need the quotes around the pattern.

Can someone point out my error please ?  Thanks !

Comment: just as a sidenote, valid polygons do need closed rings. That's why the last vertex is the same as the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DEMO:    http://jsfiddle.net/gunderjt/B5wsK/2/

```
MyTest.rings[0].join()
```

and join with no parameters delineates with commas automatically

Answer (score 2):

You may try this ([Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZSv5/2/)) using [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
MyTest = { "rings": [...] };
var str = MyTest.rings.join();
```

Result (in `str`) would be:

> -97.06138,32.837,-97.06133,32.836,-97.06124,32.834,-97.06127,32.832,-97.06138,32.837

Comment: Because `rings` is a nested array, I don't think `join()` is being used. It seems that the separator parameter has no effect and the same result can be achieved by `toString()`. See [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZSv5/3/).

Answer (score 1):

You have an object, use it - don't play with the stringified version.

```
var coords = MyTest.rings[0];
var list = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < coords.length; ++i )
  {
    list.push(coords[i][0]);
    list.push(coords[i][1]);
  }

var str = list.join(',');

// str is now "-97.06138,32.837,-97.06133...(etc.)"
```

Answer (score 0):

These are absolute basics, but you don't need to replace anything. `[]` is just an JavaScript array and not a string.

```
MyTest.rings.map(function (r) { return r.join(','); }).join(',');
// "-97.06138,32.837,-97.06133,32.836,-97.06124,32.834,-97.06127,32.832,-97.06138,32.837"
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join